# add a space between text and numbers in string

Tags: jquery

How can I add a space between text and numbers in Jquery.

I have the strings in a variable such as:

```
var month = "June2016";
```

I want it as `"June 2016".`

Comment: split the string with number 1 or 2 and add space and add the two strings back

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Regex which inserts a space between an alpha character and a numerical one. Try this:

```js
var month = "June2016".replace(/([a-z])(\d)/gi, '$1 $2');
console.log(month);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just match the number and add a space before it in the replacement

```js
var month = "June2016";
console.log(month.replace(/(\d+)/g, " $1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use match method to split the string.

```
var res = "june2016".match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g);
console.log(res[0]); // will print month
console.log(res[1]); // will print year
var result = res[0]+" "+res[1];
```

Checkout the [**fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/pvcrhL6h/)